# How many $k$ tuples of subsets $S_1,...,S_k$ are there such that $S_1 \cap ..... \cap S_k = \emptyset $.

Tags: combinatorics

How many $k$ tuples of subsets $S_1,...,S_k$ are there such that

$S_1 \cap ..... \cap S_k = \emptyset  $.

An attempt: Suppose we can make a sketch of a Venn diagram with $k$ subsets. Then there are $2^k$ total locations in the diagram, but we don't have to take their intersection since it has to be empty. Thus there are $2^{k} -1$ places to place $n$ numbers from $[n] = (1,...,n)$. Then there are $n-2^k \choose 2^k - 1$ total ways of doing this.
Can someone please provide some feedback and tell me if I am in the right track ?
I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: And these are subsets of? $\{1,2, \ldots n\}$?

Comment: the problem does not mention anything, But I think these are subsets of a set  $S$ with $n$ elements

Comment: Yeah it should be some "finite" set with cardinality atleast $k$. Otherwise the answer is clearly $0$ or infinite. Alongwith it should also be mentioned that these subsets are non-empty otherwise again just take all empty subsets and you're done.

Comment: I haven't checked that yet because the question wasn't really precise..

Comment: Can you please check ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throughout, let $[n] = \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$, and let $\mathcal{P}(S)$ denote the power set of $S$.

Given a $k$-tuple $(S_1, \cdots, S_k)$ of subsets of $[n]$ such that $\bigcap_{1\le i \le k} S_i = \emptyset$, consider the function $f: [n] \to \mathcal{P}([k])$ that takes $x \in [n]$ to the set of indices $i$ such that $x \in S_i$. In particular, since $\bigcap S_i = \emptyset$, we have $f(x) \neq [k]$ for all $x \in [n]$.

This function $f$ totally determines the $k$-tuple, since $S_i = \{x \in [n] \, : \, i \in f(x)\}$. Conversely, given any function $f: [n] \to \mathcal{P}([k])$ with $f(x) \neq [k]$ for all $x \in [n]$, we can obtain such a $k$-tuple by setting $S_i = \{x \in [n] \, : \, i \in f(x)\}$, as before.

Thus, to count the number of $k$-tuples, it suffices to count the functions satisfying the condition, of which there are evidently $(2^k -1)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

With this problem it does seem  to have its origins in a combinatorics
course   and  hence   we   may   suppose  that   it   is  asking   for
inclusion-exclusion. We get the formula (follows by inspection)

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q (2^{n-q})^k.$$

With  this  inclusion-exclusion  poset  the nodes  $P  \subseteq  [n]$
represent $k$-tuples whose  intersection is $P$ or a  superset of $P.$
This formula  assigns weight  one to $k$-tuples  who do  not intersect
because they only  appear in the $q=0$ term. Now for  a $k$-tuple that
intersects in  exactly $p$ elements it  is included in  all nodes that
are subsets of those $p$ elements. With $q$ the size of these nodes we
get the contribution

$$\sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q} (-1)^q = 0$$

because $p\ge  1.$ Therefore we  assign weight one only  to admissible
tuples  and  weight   zero  to  all  others,  which   is  the  desired
behaviour.

Simplifying the formula we get

$$2^{nk} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q 2^{-kq}
= 2^{nk} (1-2^{-k})^n = (2^k-1)^n$$

which matches the result from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may also compute the number of such $k-$ tuples by considering the complementary set.

For a fixed $X\subseteq A$ with $X\neq \emptyset$  we have $$|\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k =X\}|=(2^{n-|X|})^k$$

Moreover, $$\big\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k \neq \emptyset\big\}=\bigcup_{X\subseteq A \\ X\neq \emptyset}\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k = X\}$$ Since the above union is disjoint, $$\begin{eqnarray*}|\big\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k \neq \emptyset\big\}| &=& \sum_{X\subseteq A \\ X \neq \emptyset } |\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k = X\}| \\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{X\subseteq A \\ |X|=j} |\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k = X\}| \\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{X\subseteq A \\ |X|=j} (2^{n-j})^k \\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^n {n \choose j}(2^{k})^{n-j} \\ &=& \sum_{j=0}^n{n \choose j}(2^{k})^{n-j} - 2^{nk}   \\ &=& (1+2^{k})^n-2^{nk} \end{eqnarray*}$$ So, $$|\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k\ = \emptyset\}|=2^{nk}-|\{A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_k \neq \emptyset\}|=2^{nk+1}-(2^k+1)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $|S|=n$

It is of no loss of generality to have
$$S=\mathbb{N}_n = \{1,2,...,n\}$$

Instead of distributing items into $S_i$ for each i=1,...,k, we distribute $S_i$ into each element of S, in the sense that

Let $$T = \{S_1,S_2,...,S_k\}$$

Define $$P_i = \{\Gamma \in T \; | \; i \in \Gamma\}, \: \: 1\leq i\leq n$$

By the imposition on the intersection of all the $S_i \,'s$, we have $$P_i\not= T, \:\: 1\leq i\leq n$$
in other words, each $P_i$ is proper subset of *T*.

Indeed there are $\left(2^k-1\right)$ possible occurences of numbers of elements of each $P_i$.

Hence there are $\left(2^k-1\right)^n$ such possible ways.

the alternative would be to define a function that maps S into the set of k-tuple binary sequences

$f:S\to B_k=\{(a_1,...,a_k)\;|\;a_i \in \{0,1\}\}$

\begin{align*} f(j) = (s_1,...,s_k), \; \; \;  &s_i=1 \iff j \in S_i \\ &s_i=0 \iff j \not\in S_i \end{align*}
Indeed this is akin to the first solution.

Second alternative would be through PIE
\begin{align*} \Omega &= \left\{\left(S_1,...,S_k\right) \; | \; \forall i\in \mathbb{N}_k, \, S_i \subseteq S \right \} \\ P_i &= \left\{(S_1,...,S_k) \; \Big| \; i\in \bigcap_{j=1}^k S_j \right \}
\\ \bigcup_{i=1}^n P_i &= \left\{\left(S_1,...,S_k\right) \; \Big| \; \bigcap_{j=1}^k S_j \not= \emptyset \right \} \end{align*}
Indubitably, the value we'd seek is
$$ \left|\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n P_i \right)^c\right| = |\Omega|-\sum_{J\subseteq \mathbb{N}_n \\ J\not= \emptyset} (-1)^{|J|-1} \: \left |\; \bigcap_{j \in J} P_j \; \right| $$
Since $$ \left |\; \bigcap_{j \in J_1} P_j \; \right| = \left |\; \bigcap_{j \in J_2} P_j \; \right| = 2^{\left(n-|J_1|\right)k} , \: \; \forall J_1  , J_2 \subseteq \mathbb{N}_n$$
By symmetry, we have
\begin{align*} \left|\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n P_i \right)^c\right| &= \left(2^k\right)^n +\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^r \, \binom{n}{r} \, \left(2^k\right)^{n-r} \\  &= \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} \, (-1)^r \, \left(2^k\right)^{n-r} \\ &= \left(2^k-1\right)^n \end{align*}