# Number of regions of a venn diagram satisfying $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \supseteq S_3 \subseteq S_4 \supseteq \dotsm S_k$.

Tags: combinatorics

Question take from 5(d) of this [handout](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-a34-mathematical-problem-solving-putnam-seminar-fall-2018/assignments/MIT18_A34F18PS1.pdf).

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ elements. Let $k$ be a fixed integer, and you want to find the number of $k$-tuples $(S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k)$ satisfying:

- each $S_1 \subset S$.
- $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \supseteq S_3 \subseteq S_4 \supseteq \dotsm S_k$ where the subset and supset are alternating.

I think that first, the problem can be reduced to a venn-diagram question. For example of what I mean, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2169006/577979) and its accepted answer.
So my question is then, if we have a venn diagram of $S_1, \dots, S_k$ satisfying $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \supseteq S_3 \subseteq S_4 \supseteq \dotsm S_k$, how many regions does it have? Lets denote this number by $V(k)$.

By brute force, I compute the following first few values, $V(2) = 3, V(3) = 5, V(4) = 8, V(5) = 13$.[image]

Question: How can I find can prove a formula for $V(k)$? After such a formula is obtained, then the answer to the orginal question will be ${V(k)}^n$.

Thanks for the help! Any other ways of doing this question will also be very welcome.

**Edit.** Corrected $V(3)=5$ as mentioned by Mike Earnest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $V(3)=5$. The sequence $V(1),V(2),V(3),\dots$ goes like $2,3,5,8,13,\dots,$ Are these numbers familiar? ; )

It seems that $V(k)$ is a Fibonacci number; to prove that, it would suffice to prove that $V(k)=V(k-1)+V(k-2)$, and then to check two base cases.

Here is a good way of looking at the problem. A region in the Venn diagram is specified by a sequence of $k$ zeroes and ones, where the $i^{th}$ symbol being one means the region is inside the $i^{th}$ set, and zero otherwise. Such a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_k$ must satisfy $a_1\le a_2 \ge a_3\le a_4 \ge \dots a_k$, to agree with the inclusion restrictions on the sets. Therefore, $V(k)$ is the number of such binary sequences satisfying those alternating inequalities. We have now reduced the problem to this other question on the site: [How to simplify complicated Recursion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423389/how-to-simplify-complicated-recursion/3423417#3423417)

Comment: That is amazing, thank you!